# Explaining the problem with a column of values from a non-mutually exclusive domain

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm trying to convince the powers-that-be that their current database design is risky and inefficient. I'd like to verify whether my assumptions are correct, and I'd like help in finding technical literature and/or terminology that explains the problem in a way that sounds more convincing than my "It's bad, mmmkay."

It's parcels data. The current structure is as seen here:

```
PARCEL_ID   PARCEL_TYPE     RIGHTS_SURFACE      RIGHTS_MINERAL
46          EASEMENT            0                   0
47          DISPOSED            1                   0
47          OWNED               0                   1
```

I see two, related issues with the PARCEL_TYPE column:

1) A single column identifies ownership. However, we may own mineral rights but not surface rights. In which case, the current workflow is (as above) to create a second entry for that parcel.  The mineral rights and surface rights columns do not actually indicate ownership; they only indicate whether the value found under PARCEL_TYPE applies to them.

2) The column refers to non-mutually exclusive characteristics: ownership (current, past, never--as it applies to the surface vs minerals) and access (whether we have an easement, lease, or permit). That is, we could have a parcel that we formerly owned that we now have a permit to access; with the current data structure, we could only indicate that by creating a copy of the parcel.

To address both of these issues at once, my recommendation would be to restructure the table like so:

```
PARCEL_ID   RIGHTS_SURFACE      RIGHTS_MINERAL      ACCESS
46          NOT OWNED           NOT OWNED           EASEMENT
47          DISPOSED            OWNED               OWNED
```

This would prevent duplicate entries from referring to the same parcel, and--as far as I can tell--it would keep the possible values in fields mutually exclusive.

Is this a better (or the best) way to structure the data? And, if so, to what database management standards is this change conforming?

EDIT:
More research has brought me suspect that this results from not normalizing to the 1st, 3rd, and Boyce-Codd normal forms (and that there are some domain/key normal form issues with the table as well). Maybe throwing around that terminology will be convincing enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best argument against the existing design is that there's really no good primary key on the table (except perhaps an identity column, which I don't consider a good primary key). That makes it hard to join to other tables.

An advantage with your design is that a query can easily identify parcels where you (for instance) have mineral rights but not surface rights using a simple WHERE clause. With the existing design, this is still possible, but it's a lot messier (and not really feasible using graphical tools or entry-level SQL). This is particularly important if the table in question is a dimension table in a datawarehouse.

Comment: Great point about the primary key! That's part of what I was trying to verbalize. I think the current data managers don't see it that way, because it's a GIS dataset, and they're thinking of the location as a primary key. But, to me, that's all the more reason to avoid duplicate features: the overlapping features are causing issues with spatial analysis.